# Does Elasticsearch support POST over GET only for the _search endpoint or all?

Tags: elasticsearch

The official reference states that one can send `_search` requests also through `POST` instead of `GET` because not all clients support sending bodys with `GET` (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html). You can then insert the query parameters from the URL also as JSON directly in the body.

Now I wonder: is this true for all `GET` requests that Elasticsearch offers that need query parameters?

For example, the `_stat` endpoint (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) is documented as a `GET` request (which makes sense), but supports URI parameters. Is it safe to use `POST` in this case as well and pass the parameters in the body using JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `_search` endpoint is one of a few special cases. If you look at the source code for the `_stats` endpoint in [`RestIndicesStatsAction.java`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/admin/indices/stats/RestIndicesStatsAction.java#L44), you can see that only the GET HTTP method is supported.

Using the POST method usually makes sense only when the payload to be sent can be substantially big, which is not the case for the few parameters such as the ones accepted by the `_stats` endpoint. In that case, sending those parameters in the query string is usually more than sufficient.